# MVC3 Data binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a partial view which I pass a model to and it displays checkboxs which the user can select and this eventually gets posted with my form so that I can query their checked state and insert data into DB as required.

I want to change my partial view so that instead of taking a model that contains a list of models it take the list of models directly thus decoupling it and making it more useful as a partial view. The problem is when I do this it doesn't seem to bind the data correctly. Below is an example of the code before (working correctly and after not working).

I would very much appreciate if somebody is able to shed some light as to why my changes are not taking affect, i.e. in the after code when I inspect the posted data the list is null and in the before it is populated correctly:

**Before:**

Call the partial view:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Facilities</legend>
    <div class="display-field">
        <div>
            @{Html.RenderPartial("Partial/FacilityPartial", Model);}
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Partial view:

```
@model namespace.Models.SchoolRegisterModel
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Facilities.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Facilities[i].name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Facilities[i].facility_id)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Facilities[i].@checked, Model.Facilities[i].name);
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(
            x => x.Facilities[i].@checked,
        new
        {
            id = Model.Facilities[i].facility_id,
            @class = "RightSpacing",
            description = Model.Facilities[i].description
        }
    ) 
}
```

**After:**

Call the partial view:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Facilities</legend>
    <div class="display-field">
        <div>
            @{Html.RenderPartial("Partial/FacilityPartial", Model.Facilities);}
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<namespace.Models.facility>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).name)

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).facility_id)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).@checked, Model.ElementAt(i).name);
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(
            x => x.ElementAt(i).@checked,
        new
        {
            id = Model.ElementAt(i).facility_id,
            @class = "RightSpacing",
            description = Model.ElementAt(i).description
        }
    )
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Joe

**Finished Code (Working)**

Model:

```
public class SchoolRegisterModel
{
    // ... Lots of data 
    public string Data { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Facilities")]
    public IEnumerable<FacilityViewModel> Facilities { get; set; }
}

namespace namespace.Models
{
    public class FacilityViewModel
    {
        public FacilityViewModel()
        {
        }

        public FacilityViewModel(facility facil, bool bSelected = false)
        {
            this.Facility = facil;
            this.Selected = bSelected;
        }

        public facility Facility { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

Editor Template:

```
@model namespace.Models.FacilityViewModel
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Facility.facility_id)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Facility.name)
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Selected, Model.Facility.name)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Selected,
    new
    {
        id = Model.Facility.facility_id,
        @class = "RightSpacing",
        description = Model.Facility.description
    }
)
```

Controller:

```
// GET: /School/Register

public ActionResult Register()
{
    var viewModel = new SchoolRegisterModel();

    PopulateFacilityCollection(ref viewModel);
    return View(viewModel);
}

private void PopulateFacilityCollection(ref SchoolRegisterModel viewModel)
{
    List<FacilityViewModel> FacilityCollection = new List<FacilityViewModel>();
    foreach (facility facil in DBModel.facilities)
    {
        FacilityCollection.Add(new FacilityViewModel(facil));
    }

    viewModel.Facilities = FacilityCollection;
}
```

View:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Facility</legend>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Facilities)
        </div>
</fieldset>
```

All seems to work well now, I hope that this helps somebody else!

Comment: What is `ElementAt`?  Is that really your code?

Comment: Yes, ElementAt should get me the element at the index position, which should be the facility for that particular loop item?

Comment: Just do `x=>x.[i].name`, etc. and see what happens

Comment: This doesn't compile.. Do you mean use x=>x[i].name instead of x=>x.[i].name in which case I end up with the error mentioned below: Error 28 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<namespace.Models.facility>' Thanks Joe

Comment: Make your model a `List<T>`.  Call the partial like this `@{Html.RenderPartial("Partial/FacilityPartial", Model.Facilities).ToList();}` and type your view like this `@model List<namespace.Models.facility>`

Comment: This still doesn't work?? My new code is above (NEW CODE:) Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work?  It doesn't compile or it doesn't bind?

Comment: Sorry it doesn't bind, i.e. my model.facility collection is null when I get to the controllers post method.

Comment: Use Editor Templates! See my answer below for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you seem to be using Partial Views when you should be using Editor Templates. When using Partials, you will need to pass around the full Model in order for the Html Helpers to retain the full object hierarchy in the names/ids it generates. Since the Model Binder uses those names during deserialization, if the hierarchy is lost... the data cannot be re-saturated.

I would suggest using an Editor Template instead, this will allow you to keep the Razor code in your Partial View the same while passing only the object needed in the top level model... in your case the list.

Here is a pretty good tutorial on how to use them: http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/

Comment: That is exactly what I want thank you soo much. FYI or anybody else who is facing the same problem I found a very good simple example on a post on here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610210/how-can-i-bind-checkboxes-to-a-viewmodel-in-mvc3) in addition to the link that you provided! I will also post an updated version of my code once I have tidied it all up so that people can see it in action.